# Did not supporting git push function in git bash

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I will nearly try to pull my project to bitbucket in git bash, but I can't push it to my branch
I will type in git bash "git push" it will display that output

Unauthorized
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

why the reason for that is I will test my passkey on git bash on "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org" Unfortunately it displays the output "You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled" What i the trouble? I that and I want help with that problem.

Comment: The ssh connection is used internally by git, but you cannot ssh to the server directly, as the error message says. So your direct ssh test is not going to help. Instead, look at what privileges your ssh key has on the bitbucket server and make sure it includes access to the repo you're trying to push to.

Comment: The rest of the output could help here too.